# How can I programmatically get access to GMAIL attachments?

Tags: java, linux, email, attachment

Currently I've signed up for a subscription service that sends me data as an email attachment...it's a zip file.  I get a file everyday.

What I want is a program that runs every day that downloads the attachment from Gmail and then opens the zip file and processes it's contents.

The server I would be running this app on is running Ubuntu

I'm looking for either existing tools that will do this or a strategy that I can implement myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use JavaMail to connect to GMail's imap or pop3 interface, then fetch emails and retrieve attachments.